# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, tzoffset(None, 19800)] and datetime

Tags: python, typeerror

Getting this error when i run the following code:
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, tzoffset(None, 19800)] and datetime

Code:
compressed_set_validation = compressed_set[compressed_set['Close_Date'] >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)] # Sys.Date()-90

compressed_set_validation.shape

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue, datetime formats being compared were not the same. Just need to convert the dataframe column to the appropriate format.

```
    compressed_set['Close_Date'] =compressed_set['Close_Date'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```